# How the expected value goes on when the dependent variable is stochastic

Tags: probability

Well I am not sure its correct expression as the title, anyway

I got an equation of typical OLS, such as
$y_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}X_{t}+u_{t}$

and the ols estimate of the $\beta_{1}$ is,
$\hat{\beta}_{1}=\beta_{1}+\frac{\sum X_{t}u_{t}}{\sum X_{t}^2}$

in this way, if the variable $X_{t}$ is stochastic variable then what is the value of the expected value of the second value of the right hand side of the equation as we put the expectation up to derive the freedom from bias?

Comment: use `\hat{\beta}`

Comment: You need to assume something about the joint distribution of $(X_t,u_t)$. Usually, it's assumed that $E[u_t\mid X_t]=0$ a.s. Then by the LIE the expextation of the second term is 0.